# JSON parsing befuddlement

Tags: json, haskell, yesod

I'm working on the I/O aspect of my json server, and there's a method I just can't get right.
First, I'll give the error, then the code and datatypes involved and some commentary about the problem afterwards.

`("X-Response-Body-Start","<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html><head><title>Invalid Arguments</title></head><body><h1>Invalid Arguments</h1><ul><li>when expecting a unit constructor (U1), encountered String instead</li></ul></body></html>")`

Expecting unit contructor?

Okay here's some relevant code. Let's see if we can see where I go wrong
    `from Datatypes.hs`

```
data JobID = JobID Project Int deriving Generic

data Project = BNAP deriving (Show,Generic) -- one day to be an ADT

instance ToJSON Project where
   toJSON = toJSON . show

instance FromJSON Project

instance FromJSON JobID
instance ToJSON JobID
```

The test code

```
testReadR :: IO Value
testReadR = do
   req <- parseUrl readURI
   manager <- newManager def
   pBody <- runResourceT $ do
               reqBody <- readObject
               liftIO $ print reqBody
               Response _ _ _ body <- http (buildReq req reqBody) manager
               pBody <- body $$+- sinkParser json
               return pBody  -- (return wraps it up)
   closeManager manager
   return pBody

buildReq :: forall a (m :: * -> *) (t :: * -> *).
            ToJSON a =>
            Request t -> a -> Request m
buildReq req reqBody =
   let reqBodyBS = Data.Aeson.encode reqBody
       rHeaders = [(hContentType,pack "application/json")]
   in  req {method = fromString "POST"
           , requestBody = RequestBodyLBS reqBodyBS
           ,requestHeaders=rHeaders
           }
readObject :: ResourceT IO Value
readObject = do -- I took a bunch out because I thought simplifiying would help me
                -- solve this
   return $ Data.Aeson.toJSON $ JobID BNAP 306
```

The Handler

```
postReadR :: Handler RepJson
postReadR = do
   conf <- parseJsonBody_ :: Handler JobID        
   liftIO $ print conf
   testJ <- jsonToRepJson $ toJSON $ JobID BNAP 305
   jValue <- jsonToRepJson conf -- to be replaced with 
                                -- Either ErrorReport Response
                                -- (or something like that)
   return jValue
```

when I change the line to
`conf <- parseJsonBody_ :: Handler Value`

`print conf` yields
`Array (fromList [String "BNAP",Number 306])`

So it seems the problem lies with  String "BNAP" but I don't know why. Any ideas on how I can suss this out? Is there an obvious answer I'm not seeing?

Update : I have a new error. I'm sure I borked the `FromJSON` instance.

```
test: ResponseTimeout

instance FromJSON Project where
   parseJSON (String p) = parseJSON $ toJSON p
   parseJSON _ = mzero
```

The challenge here was that `Project` is a unary type. None of the examples I studied seemed to address that. But I know p is a `Text`, and `toJSON` can make a `Value` out of that, and `parseJSON` makes a `Parser` out of the `Value`. So it's all good right? Well, I still get the above error which is not informative at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Updated my answer with what I believe fixes your current problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
instance ToJSON Project where
   toJSON = toJSON . show

instance FromJSON Project
```

The instances don't work together. The generic `FromJSON` instance expects the generic unit constructor `U1`, but the `ToJSON` instance produces a `String "BNAP"`.

If you have a hand-written `ToJSON` instance, you also need a hand-written `FromJSON` instance.

---

```
instance FromJSON Project where
   parseJSON (String p) = parseJSON $ toJSON p
   parseJSON _ = mzero
```

`p` is a `Text`, and we have

```
instance ToJSON Text where
    toJSON = String
```

so the above instance for `Project` loops, since it expands `parseJSON (String p) = parseJSON (String p)`.

For the type as it stands now,

```
instance FromJSON Project where
    parseJSON (String "BNAP") = return BNAP
    parseJSON _               = mzero
```

should work if you have `OverloadedStrings` enabled, if not,

```
instance FromJSON Project where
    parseJSON (String p)
        | p == pack "BNAP" = return BNAP
    parseJSON _            = mzero
```